# Apple store connect doesn't show my latest build

Tags: ios, xcode, build, application-loader

I built my latest release of my iPhone app. I used XCode to build it, archive it and publish it.

Usually I see the latest build in the Apple store connect. This time it doesn't show up and I don't know why:

[image]

Comment: Did you got any email about build?

Comment: not even an email, however I just managed to fix the problem. I'm going to post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed the problem,
Till now, in XCode, under the deployment info, I had "Deployment Target = 9.1". I tried setting it to "10.1" and now my new builds show up on the online Apple developer page.

[image]

To solve the issue I had to go through the Apple help page, where I found that from now on, Apple only accepts apps build with XCode 10.1 or later

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can check the status of you uploaded builds under *Activity*. Maybe there's something wrong with your upload.

Usually you need to wait a few minutes for apple to process your uploaded version.

Also try to hover over *Build* in your screenshot. A blue + button should appear there.

Your assumption, that you need to increment the deployment target is wrong.
You only need the Xcode 10.1 (or higher) build tools. The deployment target is the minimum iOS version which you support. So building for iOS target 9.0 with Xcode 10.1 should also work.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Activity** and check the **binary** version which you have uploaded. Check the status. The newer binary still is in the waiting process or have some issues. You should get a confirmation mail regarding successful uploads.

Comment: no Activity anywhere anymore